# react native expo

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, app, expo, paquetes-npm

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo un problema, inicio una app con react native expo, inicializo con npm install -g expo-cli, luego hago un expo init con el nombre de mi pryecto, elijo como quiero inicializar el proyecto, al ejecutar el npm satart lo abro desde la web y me da muchos errores, el mayor error es que tiene hooks por defectos que no pueden ser ejecutados y no me renderiza lo que viene por defecto ni nada de lo que haga, como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: bueno, ahi acabo de subir la imagen de los errores que me da la consola, esto es cuando inicializo de cero una app, yo no toque nada, hice solamente las instalaciones y lo ejecute y me da esos errores